# how to open 3ds files with python

Tags: python, file, 3d, 3dsmax

I am new to 3d world. I would like to open 3ds files with python and visualize the objects.

I could not find any easy and straight forward way to play with 3ds max files.

Can you let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: python has no native graphics capabilities... there's gui libraries you can bolt onto the side, but that doesn't mean you're going to magically transform python into a "free" clone of 3ds.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, there are some advanced graphics libraries out there for advanced usage, however Blender, (an application developed in python) supports python scripting. There are even a simple drag and drop game engine for simpler tasks.